# Changing reactive link in a ul list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a ul list as menu and I would like to set active link. This is the code:

```
<ul id="list" class="date">
    <li class="element"><ul><li class="year"><a id="year2004" href ="2004.html" target="edicion" >2004</a></li></ul></li>
    <li class="element"><ul><li class="year"><a id="year2005" href ="2005.html" target="edicion" >2005</a></li></ul></li>
    <li class="element"><ul><li class="year"><a id="year2006" href ="2006.html" target="edicion">2006</a></li></ul></li>
    <li class="element"><ul><li class="year"><a id="year2007" href ="2007.html" target="edicion">2007</a></li></ul></li>
    <li class="element"><ul><li class="year"><a id="year2008" href ="2008.html" target="edicion">2008</a></li></ul></li>
    <li class="element"><ul><li class="year"><a id="year2009" href ="2009.html" target="edicion">2009</a></li></ul></li>
    <li class="element"><ul><li class="year"><a id="year2010" href ="2010.html" target="edicion">2010</a></li></ul></li>
    <li class="element"><ul><li class="year"><a id="year2011" href ="2011.html" target="edicion">2011</a></li></ul></li>
    <li class="element"><ul><li class="year"><a id="year2012" href ="2012.html" target="edicion">2012</a></li></ul></li>
    <li class="element"><ul><li class="year"><a id="year2013" href ="2013.html" target="edicion">2013</a></li></ul></li>
    <li class="element"><ul><li class="year"><a id="year2014" href ="2014.html" target="edicion">2014</a></li></ul></li>
    <li class="element"><ul><li class="year"><a id="year2015" href ="2015.html" target="edicion">2015</a></li></ul></li>
</ul>
```

I set the first active link with this code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#year2015").addClass("active");
    });
</script>
```

How can I switch the active status when I click on a link?

Thanks in advance ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would revisit your markup, as you're using one list per list item.
It seems you only need one list, so get rid of the nested `<ul>` tags :-)

To handle the active class I would do the following:

```
$('.date a').on("click", function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    $('.date a').removeClass("active");
    elem.addClass("active");
});
```

This should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.date ul li ul li a').click(function(){ /* capture the click */
      $('.date ul li ul li a').removeClass('active'); /* remove all other active classes */
      $(this).addClass('active'); /* add active class to clicked link */
    }
});
```

OR use wildcards for readability

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[id^=year20]").click(function(){
    $("[id^=year20]").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a Common class to all the anchors and toggle the active/inactive using that class name.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".year_anchor").click(function () {
             $('#list a').removeClass('active'); 
             $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    });
```

```css
.active { color: black }
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<ul id="list" class="date">
    <li class="element">
        <ul>
            <li class="year"><a class= "year_anchor" id="year2004" href ="2004.html" target="edicion" >2004</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
        <ul>
            <li class="year"><a class= "year_anchor" id="year2005" href ="2005.html" target="edicion" >2005</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
        <ul>
            <li class="year"><a class= "year_anchor" id="year2006" href ="2006.html" target="edicion">2006</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
        <ul>
            <li class="year"><a class= "year_anchor" id="year2007" href ="2007.html" target="edicion">2007</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
        <ul>
            <li class="year"><a class= "year_anchor" id="year2008" href ="2008.html" target="edicion">2008</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
        <ul>
            <li class="year"><a class= "year_anchor" id="year2009" href ="2009.html" target="edicion">2009</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
        <ul>
            <li class="year"><a class= "year_anchor" id="year2010" href ="2010.html" target="edicion">2010</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
        <ul>
            <li class="year"><a class= "year_anchor" id="year2011" href ="2011.html" target="edicion">2011</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
        <ul>
            <li class="year"><a class= "year_anchor" id="year2012" href ="2012.html" target="edicion">2012</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
        <ul>
            <li class="year"><a class= "year_anchor" id="year2013" href ="2013.html" target="edicion">2013</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
        <ul>
            <li class="year"><a class= "year_anchor" id="year2014" href ="2014.html" target="edicion">2014</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
        <ul>
            <li class="year"><a class= "year_anchor" id="year2015" href ="2015.html" target="edicion">2015</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[Please check the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sravanaravind/gg6n42L1/)

Comment: `$('a').removeClass('active'); ` is dangerous - what is there are other menus or others uses of same class on links - personally I'd narrow it down a bit